# tbb GettingStarted example is not compiling

Tags: c++, linux, redhat, tbb

I have sources the tbbvars.csh file.
I have opened the example directory as I was guided `(/GettingStarted/sub_string_finder)`, and run make.
Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
sub_string_finder.cpp:32:30: error: tbb/parallel_for.h: No such file or directory
sub_string_finder.cpp:33:31: error: tbb/blocked_range.h: No such file or directory
sub_string_finder.cpp:35: error: tbb is not a namespace-name
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: The include path is not set correctly. Look where is the parallel_for.h file located and set the include path correctly

Answer (score 1):

You must include `tbb` directory to compile your example